# Usb wireless mouse and keyboard freezing only when external screen is connected

Tags: 16.04

Usb wireless mouse and keyboard freezing only when external screen is connected.

its freezing from time to time, for a while, and after that it working properly for a while again.

Comment: To possibly confirm: my mounse and keyboard freeze from time to time anyway. I use Logitech unifying receiver and I paired the mouse and keyboard with [Solaar][1]. 

I tried a second receiver. Same problem.


  [1]: https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu 16.04 was upgraded from 14.04 with "Laptop Mode Tools" installed and I have the same problem.

In my case, I found it might caused by "Enable module usb-autosuspend" option of LMT.
However, turning option off seems no effect on the problem.

Here is what I do and it works...
edit **/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf** and change the value of **AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT**. (I changed it to 300 seconds)

Also, you can solve this problem by adding your USB device (mouse/keyboard) ID into LMT's blacklist.

1. under Terminal, use lsusb to find out your USB device ID
2. in the **usb-autosuspend.conf** as mentioned above, add the device ID to **AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST** option.